# Can't Remove Bluetooth Device despite no entry in registry

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-registry, bluetooth

I have a machine running windows 10.

I am trying to remove a bluetooth device and reconnect it. At the start, when I tried to remove the device through the windows' settings I got the message that "remove failed". The same thing happened when I tried to remove it through the control panel.

I removed the driver for the device in device manager, but after restarting, the device still persisted. The driver was not listed in device manager though.

The last step I took was to remove the entry for the device in the registry file, but after restarting the device was still there. There is currently no entry in the registry file. I removed it from:

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\BTHPORT\Parameters\Devices
```

Right now, I see the device in the windows settings and in the "devices and printers" section in the control panel and I can't remove either one. There is no entry for the device in the registry nor is there a driver for the device. I also don't have a backup of the registry before I removed the entry.

How do I get rid of the thing so I can reconnect it? The device is a pair of headphones so it's something I use a lot.

Comment: 1. Look in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Upgrade\PnP\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceMigration\Devices\BTHENUM\ for the device by *-FriendlyName*. 2. See https://www.saintlad.com/cant-remove-bluetooth-devices-on-windows-10/ for more ways to remove it.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I don't have the Upgrade directory inside of Setup

Answer (score 7):

You can try this **PowerShell** wrapper for the `BluetoothRemoveDevice()` api. Copy & paste the code below into a **PowerShell** window, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```powershell
$Source = @"
   [DllImport("BluetoothAPIs.dll", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
   static extern UInt32 BluetoothRemoveDevice(IntPtr pAddress);

   public static UInt32 Unpair(UInt64 BTAddress) {
      GCHandle pinnedAddr = GCHandle.Alloc(BTAddress, GCHandleType.Pinned);
      IntPtr pAddress     = pinnedAddr.AddrOfPinnedObject();
      UInt32 result       = BluetoothRemoveDevice(pAddress);
      pinnedAddr.Free();
      return result;
   }
"@

Function Get-BTDevice {
    Get-PnpDevice -class Bluetooth |
      ?{$_.HardwareID -match 'DEV_'} |
         select Status, Class, FriendlyName, HardwareID,
            # Extract device address from HardwareID
            @{N='Address';E={[uInt64]('0x{0}' -f $_.HardwareID[0].Substring(12))}}
}

################## Execution Begins Here ################

$BTR       = Add-Type -MemberDefinition $Source -Name "BTRemover"  -Namespace "BStuff" -PassThru
$BTDevices = @(Get-BTDevice) # Force array if null or single item

Do {
   If ($BTDevices.Count) {
      "`n******** Bluetooth Devices ********`n" | Write-Host
      For ($i=0; $i -lt $BTDevices.Count; $i++) {
         ('{0,5} - {1}' -f ($i+1), $BTDevices[$i].FriendlyName) | Write-Host
      }
      $selected = Read-Host "`nSelect a device to remove (0 to Exit)"
      If ([int]$selected -in 1..$BTDevices.Count) {
         'Removing device: {0}' -f $BTDevices[$Selected-1].FriendlyName | Write-Host
         $Result = $BTR::Unpair($BTDevices[$Selected-1].Address)
         If (!$Result) {"Device removed successfully." | Write-Host}
         Else {"Sorry, an error occured." | Write-Host}
      }
   }
   Else {
      "`n********* No devices found ********" | Write-Host
   }
} While (($BTDevices = @(Get-BTDevice)) -and [int]$selected)
```

When run, it will list Bluetooth devices:

```bash
PS > . "C:\Users\keith\Sandbox\Bluetooth Removal\removedevice v1.0.ps1"

******** Bluetooth Devices ********

    1 - Chill Out
    2 - LG HBS730

Select a device to remove (0 to Exit):
```

If the device isn't listed there, I would guess it's a namespace artifact.

Comment: I ran the code and it was in that list

Comment: Didn't see the end prompt at first sorry. When I try to remove the device I get an error message. After trying to remove the device though, the name disappeared from the list. Does that make it a namespace artifact?

Comment: I'm not sure. That was just a guess based on one of the common casuses of "dead icons" on the Desktop.

Comment: This code actually worked for me!

Comment: @Serafeim: Glad to hear it, though slightly offended at your tone of surprise... :-P   Thanks for the feedback and upvote!

Comment: The device I want to remove is listed by this script, but when I type the number of the device to remove it, the response is "Sorry, an error occured".  And the device is not removed.

Comment: This worked! Thank you OP! But wow, when did Windows become less user-friendly than Linux? How is running a random shell script from the internet the best way remove a Bluetooth device in 2023?

Comment: @DavidEtler: "Random"?!?!? I'm flattered... :D  Don't think of it as the best way, think of it as a last resort...

Answer (score 1):

This is what fixed it for me:

1. Open Device Manager
2. Expand "Bluetooth". You should be able to see your Bluetooth device listed there.
3. At the top of Device Manager, open the View menu and choose "Show hidden devices". With "Show hidden devices" enabled, you may be able to see an additional Bluetooth device with the same name as your device and a pale blue icon (the pale blue indicating that it is a hidden device).
4. Right click on the hidden device and chose "Uninstall device".
5. Now, go to Settings > Bluetooth & devices and you should now be able to remove your Bluetooth device.